# GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies Error when building Xamarin.Android in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I build my Xamarin.Android project in Visual Studio I get the following error. Strange thing is that it worked 2 days ago, but since then I did not change any code.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task could not be instantiated from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll". 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(String name, Object[] args)
at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies..ctor()   2_MFOMobile.Droid           


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.    2_MFOMobile.Droid
```

Comment: Have you updated xamarin in past two days? Looks like that the exception is about encryption, is that possible that you share a minimal reproducible demo?

Comment: found the problem. One of the sysadmins had closed some security on our companies network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS). If possible you can disable FIPS by going to Administrative Tools | Local Security Policy | Local Polices | Security Options |  System cryptography: Use FIPS. Change the setting to Disabled.

Note that, if your PC is part of a Windows Domain, there may be a Group Policy that re-enables this setting every time you reboot your PC.

Comment: unfortunately my PC is part of e group policy. Luckily they changed the policy :)